# More efficient way of counting the number of values within an interval?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

I want to determine how many numbers of an input-array (up to 50000) lie in each of my given intervals (many).

Currently, I'm trying to do it with this algorithm, but it is far too slow:

Example-array: {-3, 10, 5, 4, -999999, 999999, 6000}
Example-interval: [0, 11] (inclusive)

1. Sort array - `O(n * log(n))`. (-999999, -3, 4, 5, 10, 6000, 999999)
2. Find min_index: `array[min_index] >= 0` - `O(n)`. (for my example, min_index == 2).
3. Find max_index: `array[max_index] <= 11` - `O(n)`. (for my example, max_index == 4).
4. If both indexes exists, then `Result == right_index - left_index + 1` (for my example, Result = (4 - 2 + 1) = 3).

Comment: Why don't you just go through the array from start to end and count directly? O(n)

Comment: @Deduplicator, I have many intervals.

Comment: As the array is sorted, you may get `min_index` in logarithm time.

Comment: @Jarod42: Still bound by the sort.

Comment: What is the maximum and minimum value of the array element?

Comment: @Max: Forgive me my question, but are you sure that you haven't I/O problems? Maybe you are using std::cin and std::cout with I/O synchronization and you should add `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` on the begin of main for better time?

Comment: @Tacet, It is OK. I/O works with files.

Comment: @Max: C++ iostreams are very slow.  Make sure to measure the I/O time and counting time separately, don't assume that I/O is optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have good idea, but it needs amendments. You should find begin and end of interval in `O(lg n)` time using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). If n is length of array and q is number of questions `[a, b]` you have O(n+q*n) time, with binary search it's `O((n + q) lg n)` (`n lg n` from sorting array).
The advantage of this solution is simplicity, because C++ have [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). And you can use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). It's just a few lines of code.

If q is equal to n, this algorithm has `O(n lg n)` complexity. Could be better? Not at all. Why? Because the problem is equivalent to sorting. As is well known, it is impossible to obtain a better computational complexity. (Sorting by means of comparison.)

Comment: The order would still be determined by the sort, not good enough.

Comment: @Tacet, I can not use binary search, because `[a, b]` may not be contained in a array.

Comment: @Deduplicator, yep, It is my fault, I understood my error.

Comment: @Max: If I understand the problem, it doesn't matter. You should find first not bigger than p, and first bigger than q. Binsearch is still good.

Comment: Re-stating my comment: The complexity of your proposal is still determined by the complexity of sorting which is of the order O(n log n), which OP stated is not good enough. BTW: How is RMQ relevant to the question?

Comment: Ugh. My bad.  I went for a tee and I forgot what was the question about. Sorry and thx. And yes, It's still determined by the sort complexity. But, earlier for q~n it was `O(n^2)`, now it's O(n lg n).

Comment: This is the method I would use and in python, the [bisect](http://pymotw.com/2/bisect/) module would have worked beautifully with this

Comment: @Tacet, I tried std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound. And you can use std::distance instead of my implementation. It is work!

Comment: @Max: I'm glad I could be helpful. :)

Comment: I think you get your choice of `O(q lg q + n lg q)` or `O(n lg n + q lg n)`, because you can choose to sort the intervals instead of the data array.  So the best approach depends on whether `n` or `q` is larger.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's true, but it's not necessary. In the algorithmic tasks, it isn't common to make this kind of optimization, only in very specific cases. Here n is so small, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple O(n<sub>input</sub>*m<sub>intervals</sub>) algorithm:

For ease of implementation, we use half-open intervals. Convert yours as needed.

1. Convert your intervals to half-open intervals (Always prefer half-open intervals)
2. Save all limits in an array.
3. For all elements in the input

   - For all elements in the limits-array

     - Increment the count if the input is smaller than the limit
4. Go through your intervals and get the answers by subtracting the counts for the corresponding limits.

For a slight performance-boost, sort the limits-array in step 2.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I do not have time to implement your algorithm, but I think that everything would be okay.

Comment: You can pull off O((n+m)lg m) with a variant.

Answer (score 1):

Create a std::map of your numbers to their index in the sorted array.

From your example map[-999999] = 0, map[-3] = 1, ... map[999999] = 7.

To find an interval, find the lowest number higher than or equal to the min (using map.lower_bound()), and find the first number higher than the max (using map.upper_bound()).

You can now subtract the lower index from the upper index to find the number of elements in that range in O(log n).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that algorithm O(n*lg n)?

Comment: Its O(n lg n + q lg n).

Comment: @patros, I tried this way. Unfortunately, It is slower, than I need.

Comment: Creating the sorted array and index is (n*log n). Finding each interval count is O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> interval;
typedef std::map<interval,size_t> answers;
typedef std::vector<interval> questions;

// O((m+n)lg m)
answers solve( std::vector<int>& data, questions const& qs ){
  // m = qs.size()
  // n = data.size()

  answers retval;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>> edges;
  edges.reserve( q.size()+1 );
  // O(m) -- all start and ends of intervals is in edges
  for ( auto q:qs ) {
    edges.emplace_back( q.first, 0 );
    edges.emplace_back( q.second, 0 );
  }
  // O(mlgm) -- sort
  std::sort(begin(edges),end(edges));
  edges.emplace_back( std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), 0 );
  // O(m) -- remove duplicates
  edges.erase(std::unique(begin(edges),end(edges)),end(edges));
  // O(n lg m) -- count the number of elements < a given edge:
  for(int x:data ){
    auto it = std::lower_bound( begin(edges), end(edges), std::make_pair(x,0) );
    it->second++;
  }
  // O(m)
  size_t accum = 0;
  for(auto& e:edges) {
    accum += edges.second;
    edges.second = accum;
  }
  // now edge (x,y) states that there are y elements < x.

  // O(n lg m) -- find the edge corresponding
  for(auto q:questions){
    auto low = std::lower_bound(begin(edges), end(edges),
      std::make_pair(q.first, size_t(0))
    );
    auto high = std::upper_bound(begin(edges), end(edges),
      std::make_pair(q.second, size_t(0))
    }
    size_t total = high->second - low->second;
    answers.emplace(q,total);
  }
  return answers;
}
```

`O((n+m)lg m)`, where n is the integer count, m is the number of intervals, and x is the average number of intervals each interval overlaps with.

Comment: `O((n+m) lg m)`, ok but here n is small, so probably m could be large. `O((n+m) lg n)` is more easy to write and probably faster. Further `O((n+m) lg n)` can be online and need less memory.